# How can I copy a column value from excel to csv file without using ComObject

Tags: excel, powershell, comobject

I'm new to Power shell. I have a number of excel files (500+) having a column Animal Count that I would like to save in a new '.csv' file. I have a code to do this using excel Com Objects.

I want to achieve the same without using ComObjects. Could anyone help me in achieving this.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel - "This PowerShell Module allows you to read and write Excel files without installing Microsoft Excel on your system. No need to bother with the cumbersome Excel COM-object."

Answer (score 0):

Download PSExcel module from
https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel
Import it using **Import-Module**.

then use the following code:

```
$AnimalCount = @()
$Source = 'D:\Test'  # the path to where the Excel files are
ForEach ($File in Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.xlsx' -File) {
$Excel = New-Excel -Path $File
$Cell = ($Excel | Get-WorkSheet | % {$_.Cells | ? {$_.Text -eq "AnimalCount"}})
$count = (($Excel | Get-WorkSheet -Name $Cell.Worksheet).Cells | ? {($_.Start.Row -eq $Cell.Start.Row) -and ($_.Start.Column -eq $Cell.Start.Column + 1)}).Text
$AnimalCount += [PsCustomObject] @{'File' = $File.FullName; 'AnimalCount' = $count }
}
$AnimalCount | Format-Table -AutoSize
$AnimalCount | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\AnimalCount.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

The best thing here is that you do not need excel to be installed on the machine that runs this script.

Comment: Thanks @dread1, But im getting below error whem im running this script. Could you please help me.                                                                                                                 'New-Excel : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:7 char:26
+ $Excel = New-Excel -Path $File
+                          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Excel], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-Excel '

Comment: Ooopps. my bad...
Replace `$File` with `$File.VersionInfo.FileName`. This will give you a proper path string to a file.

Comment: Thanks @dread1, Can i also count the no of rows  in a excel sheet by using this PSExcel ?

Comment: Of course! technically speaking you can do absolutelly everything there....
`New-Excel -Path $File` command loads your excel file into an object and you can manipulate with as you wish...  Please refer to PSExcel module functions, you'll find alot of usefull stuff there. And if there is something missing (like edit of individual cells - you can always write your own function for it using Object that you load with `New-Excel` function. How do you need to count the rows? Per worksheet in your XLSX doc or per entire document?

Comment: I want the count entire rows in worksheet and also count based on a filter criteria

Comment: This code will give you rows count for worksheet with "AnimalCount" cell:
`$rows_count = ($Excel | Get-WorkSheet -Name $Cell.Worksheet).Dimension.Rows`. It does not exclude empty rows.